# ¿Cómo crear un bean que cree una instancia de HelloServiceImpl?

Tags: java, spring

Tengo que definir un bean que cree una instancia dentro de la clase `HelloServiceImpl`, así está estructurada la clase:

```
package me.jmll.utm.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/** 1(a) Define que Spring cree una instancia de HelloServiceImpl */
//Escribe tu código aquí {

//} 
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {    
    @Override
    public String getHello(String name) {
        return String.format("Welcome %s!", name).toString();
    }
}
```

En otro programa lo ingresé como:

```
public HelloService HelloServiceImpl;
```

Pero no sé si es correcta la declaración

---

**Agrego luego de las respuestas recibidas:**

Tengo muchos archivos, en realidad tengo que hacer muchas modificaciones a varios archivos.

3. En la implementación del servicio `me.jmll.utm.HelloService`, `src/main/java/me/jmll/utm/HelloServiceImpl.java` realiza lo siguiente:

   1. Define que Spring cree una instancia de `HelloServiceImpl` con la anotación requerida.

La clase HomeController.java

```
package me.jmll.utm.web;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private HelloService helloService;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simplemente selecciona el template home.jsp para
     * interpretarlo como respuesta
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

    /**
     * Crea un Response Body con un servicio en específico.
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"name"})
    public String homeName(Locale locale, Model model, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! {} The client locale is {}.", name, locale);

        return helloService.getHello(name);
    }

    /** 2(a) Inyectar HelloService en HomeController */
    // Escribe tu código aquí {

    // } 
    public void setHelloService(HelloService helloService)
    {
        this.helloService = helloService;
    }
}
```

La clase HelloService.java

```
package me.jmll.utm.web;

public interface HelloService {
    public String getHello(String name);
}
```

Y si me dan un beans en el archivo rootContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="me.jmll.utm">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Comment: La respuesta que he publicado cumple con lo que solicitas. Solo deberías agregar `@Inject` o `@Autowired` en la definición del campo en tu controlador.

Answer (score 3):

Para que Spring pueda reconocer el bean, debes configurarlo como un bean reconocible por el framework. Puesto que solo te dicen que uses código, es muy probable que tu proyecto esté basado en configuración por anotaciones. Lo que necesitas es anotar tu clase como `@Service`:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {
}
```

Luego, en la clase donde necesitas que Spring inyecte una instancia de este bean, declaras el campo como la interfaz y además debes marcarlo como `@Autowired`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

//definición de otro bean de Spring
//con su anotación particular
public class AlgunBeanManejadoPorSpring {

    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;
}
```